# Finding Lyapunov function to show origin is stable

Tags: dynamical-systems, lyapunov-functions

Consider the system
\begin{cases} \dot{x}=-2y+yz \\ \dot{y}=x-xz \\ \dot{z}=xy \end{cases}
I need to find a Lyapunov function of the form $V(x,y,z)=ax^2+bx^2+cz^2$ to show that the origin $(0,0,0)$ is Lyapunov stable. How do I choose the constants $a,b,c$?

 I need $V(0,0,0)=0$, which is true and $V(x,y,z)>0$ is any neighbourhood of the origin, which is true as long as $a,b,c>0$.

 Then $\dot{V}(x,y,z)=2ax\dot{x}+2by\dot{y}+2cz\dot{z}=-4axy+2axyz+2bxy-2bxyz+2cxyz$.

 I can take $b=c$ to get $\dot{V}(x,y,z)=-4axy+2axyz+2bxy$.

 What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of imposing $b=c$ just collect the similar terms in the expression $\nabla V\cdot X$ you have just computed so that you just need to solve the non-singular linear system:
\begin{cases}
-4a+2b=0 \\
2a-2b+2c=0.
\end{cases}
At this point you will get infinitely many Lyapunov functions indexed by $a\in\mathbb{R}$ for instance and you can conclude.

Comment: I see, so the origin is Lyapunov stable if and only if $\dot{V}(x,y,z) \leq 0$ and in my case I have $\dot{V}(x,y,z) = 0$.

Comment: @wwinters57 when $\dot{V}(x,y,z) \leq 0$ the system would be asymptotically stable, which is a stronger notion of stability than [Lyapunov stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Definition_for_continuous-time_systems).

Comment: I think it is the other way round: the system is Lyapunov stable if $\dot{V}(x,y,z) \leq 0$ for all points in a neighbourhood of $(0,0,0)$ and it is asymptotically stable if $\dot{V}(x,y,z) < 0$.

Comment: If you just need stability showing that there exists a $V$ s.t. $\nabla V \cdot X =0$ is enough.